# How to express "organization in charge" in a formal manner

Tags: expressions, phrase-requests

I've been asked to proofread a description of a project/a request for financing. I can't help being bothered by the wording of the titles (though this may very well be part of some kind of standard template):

[image]

"Responsible" seems like the wrong way to express the organization in charge of carrying out the project. It seems to imply that the organization is responsible as opposed to irresponsible....

Is my interpretation correct and what would be a better way of expressing this?

Principal organization? Organization in charge? Organization in charge of project?

Comment: reginal tourism?  Visits to rhe queen?

Comment: The responsible organization seems just to be the organization responsible for carrying out the project.

Comment: It's a bit too vague. There may be one organisation that sets standards, another with ultimate legal responsibility, another that inspects the result, another that provides finance or guarantees completion, another that provides administration or project management, one that answers queries and interfaces with third parties, plus various designers, architects, engineers, consultants, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I answer only because you are new to the site. The question may still be closed by others for lack of research or because it suits the English Language Learners site.

> [Cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/responsible)
> *responsible*:
> to have control and authority over something or someone and the duty of taking care of it, him, or her

Hence the agency has the duty and authority to deal with the project. There is no suggestion of its being *responsible* as the antonym of *irresponsible*.

Comment: Please look at the site guidelines/help to see what makes a good question.